JsonSchema validation on date
I'm using React version "react": "^16.13.1", with antD version "@rjsf/antd": "^4.2.3",
with JsonSchema version @types/json-schema": "^7.0.5".
I wish to create a JsonSchema that is able to validate startDate and endDate.
More in particular:
when startDate is more than endDate I wish to receive an error.
This is my JSONschema:
 {
      "title": "FormSchema",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Nome",
          "span": 8
        },
        "startDate": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date",
          "title": "startDate",
          "span": 6
        },
        "endDate": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date",
          "title": "endDate",
          "span": 6
        },
        "attributes": {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "Insert house data",
          "span": 12,
          "properties": {
            "nameHouse": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "Name",
              "span": 6
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "startDate": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
              },
              "endDate": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
              }
            },
            "required": ["startDate", "endDate"]
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "endDate": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date",
                "formatExclusiveMinimum": {
                  "$data": "1/startDate"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    ```


this is not supported by JSON Schema specification.  you may find some implementations have their own extensions that support it.  I'm aware of one in .NET but I guess that doesn't help you.
